# Load library into existing environment (equivalent to "local" parameter of "source")?

Tags: r

I am sourcing util functions in production into an environment to encapsulate (and group) the helper functions:

Helper file:

```
# File: Helper.R
hello <- function() {
  print("Hello world")
}
```

Client:

```
helper <- new.env()
source("Helper.R", local=helper)
helper$hello()   # call the helper function
```

How can I migrate my sourced "Helper.R" into a library without breaking the calls of the sourced functions?

What I want is something like

```
helper <- new.env()
library(Helper, local=helper)
helper$hello()   # call the helper function (loaded from the library now)
```

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Another way would be to source into a namespace (instead of an environment) and use `::` instead of `$`, but a question for this has no satifying answer: http://stackoverflow.com/q/15620404/4468078

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `box::use()` function in the [‘box’ package](https://klmr.me/box/).

Then the following attaches a package locally:

```r
box::use(pkg[...])
```

Alternatively, and potentially closer to what you actually want to do, you could use the following simpler code:

```r
box::use(pkg)
```

Now the package is not attached at all, and its exported objects can be accessed via `pkg$obj`. This is somewhat similar to base R’s `loadNamespace` function, but does considerably more behind the scenes.

Finally, consider not putting your helper code into a package at all, but rather distributing it as a *module*. This is after all what the ‘box’ package was designed for: instead of creating a package, just distribute your `helper.r` code file (or folder) and then use it as follows:

```
box::use(./helper)
```

See the package website and [vignette](https://klmr.me/box/articles/box.html) for a detailed description.

Comment: Great package, esp. the feature to make the function comments available as help (which `source` cannot do). I hope the `modules` package will find its way into CRAN soon

Comment: @RYoda Unfortunately it wasn’t soon, but the completely rewritten package [is now on CRAN](https://cran.r-project.org/package=box) under its new name, ‘box’.

Answer (score 1):

Adding to the list of suggestions you can also consider to use the [modules](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/modules/vignettes/modulesInR.html) package on CRAN (note I am the author). When you have your `Helper.R` file with:

```
hello <- function() {
  print("Hello world")
}
```

you can use

```
helper <- modules::use("Helper.R")
helper$hello()
```

to encapsulate your helper functions in their own environment. The package also provides some functions to manipulate the local namespace of a module (imports/exports).

Answer (score 0):

Another way could be:

```
# getNamespace returns the environment representing the name space name. The namespace is loaded if necessary.
# Internal function to support reflection on namespace objects!
env <- getNamespace("data.table")
cars <- env$as.data.table(mtcars)
```

This examples makes all objects of the package `data.table` available via the environment variable `env`.

**Note: It uses an internal R function (I have no idea how big the risk of changes of this internal function really is).**

Answer (score 0):

I have found another package called `import` (similar to "modules") that allows importing packages into an environment:

https://github.com/smbache/import

This package is also on CRAN:

```
install.packages("import")
```

It allows importing selected, all exported ("public") or all (even not exported) functions of a package.

Example:

```
import::from(dplyr, arrange, .into = "datatools")
```

The `import::from` function is a convenient wrapper around `getExportedValue`.